# Get round number from rand

Tags: ruby

How I can get always round number from Ruby rand method between the interval `rand(1..99999999)`.

For Example I want to get as a result for example 1000 or 100000

Comment: What do you mean by *"circular number"*?

Comment: Sorry post is updated

Comment: What does round mean? Divisible by 10? Or divisible by certain power of 10? Like are `110`, `120`, etc round numbers or is it just `100`, `200`?

Answer (score 7):

Randomize the power of `10`:

```
10 ** rand(1..9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
('1' + '0' * (0..10).sample).to_i
```